# database import error using pgadmin 4 v4.28 in ubuntu20.4

Tags: postgresql, database

I m trying upload database file in local server which name postgresql  pgadmin4 v4.28 and facing request timeout issues  how can solve this ?
I m also increase max  upload file limit and have made changes in postgresql but could not .
os Name : ubuntu 20.04
screen shoot link below here

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hALd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is already on the same machine, rather than upload again, you should be able to import it directly into PostgreSQL:

```
psql -U {username} {database} < data_dump.sql
```

Be sure to change `{username}` and `{database}` for your needs.

Comment: I m still unable to import database    psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: To resolve this PostgreSQL will need to have an account with the same name as your login or use `sudo -u postgres psql {database} < data_dump.sql` (assuming the `postgres` account has read access to the `data_dump.sql` file. Alternatively, you can change the authentication method in PostgreSQL to something a little more forgiving. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/AtulKsol/4470d377b448e56468baef85af7fd614) has a step-by-step that shows how to change from peer authentication to md5.